# "spill" vs "leakage" vs "leak"

Tags: word-usage

Is there anything different between "***oil leakage*"**, "**oil spill**" and ***"oil leak"***? And unltimately, is spill different to *leak* or *spill* significantly?

Comment: Is spill different from spill??

Answer (score 1):

Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20oil%20leak%2Can%20oil%20leakage&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20oil%20leak%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20oil%20leakage%3B%2Cc0), ***an oil leakage*** is relatively uncommon compared to ***an oil leak***. For most practical purposes they'll mean *exactly* the same thing, but personally I feel that a ***leakage*** more strongly alludes to *the fluid that leaks out*, whereas a ***leak*** alludes to *the location from which fluid leaks out*.

And ***an oil spillage*** very definitely refers to the leaked fluid itself. This usage almost always treats the leaked fluid as an environmental contaminant, where ***leak / leakage*** is usually in reference to something "lost" from its original location / function (as the lubricant in a car engine, a valuable cargo being stored / transported, etc.).

Note that ***spillage*** (less commonly, ***spill***) is particularly likely to be used in relation to "industrial scale" accidental oil loss / escape from ocean-going transportation tankers, and things like the [Deepwater Horizon](https://www.britannica.com/event/Deepwater-Horizon-oil-spill-of-2010) oil release of 2010.

Answer (score 0):

> The word **Leak** and **Leakage** refers the broken objects that
>   containing liquids. this objects may have to repair.
>
> The word **Spill** refers we drop-out the unwanted or impurity liquids
>   from containing objects.